# Can I Automate a Task in Sketch?

Tags: sketchapp

I'm trying to create an agenda on Sketch (don't ask me why I chose Sketch) and I really don't want to enter each in date for each page of the agenda. Is there an automated way to do this so that the date is updated for each new artboard (page)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no.

The easiest way, and still a little complicated, is to use symbols for the dates of the agenda. Then you can go by hand and add/remove dates as needed in the symbol inspector view of the base art board you're using it in.

This is advanced nesting of symbols as such, so you may want to brush up on this if you're not too familiar.